# хочу добавить текст на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

почему-то не задаются параметры, которые хочу передать
создаю по нажатию другую кнопку, у которой должен быть текст этой же кнопки, но другой класс

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addSpell').on('click', function(){
        $('.placeMySpells').append('<button />', {text: "add spell", class: 'mySpell'});
    });
</script>
```

вот кнопка создается, но текста у нее нет(

Answer (score 0):

[Документация по jQuery .append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) говорит нам, что данный метод принимает в кач-ве аргументов только функцию, что возвращает далее перечисленные эл-ты, или же сами эл-ты:

> DOM element, text node, array of elements and text nodes, HTML string, or jQuery object

Самый простой вариант решения вашей проблемы - HTML string:

```
$('.placeMySpells').append('<button class="mySpell">add spell</button>');
```

Comment: Ну или `.append($('<button />').addClass('mySpell').text('add spell'));`

Comment: @De.Minov поэтому и написал - самый простой вариант. Вопрос показываем что даже append - сложно, а тут ещё addClass и text какие-то взялись